# How do you prove the Multi-Factorial formula.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For $n\in\mathbb{Z}_0,m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$,

$n!_m=n\underbrace{!\cdots!}_{\text{m}}=\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{\lceil{n/m-1}\rceil}(n-km)$

Using this formula, we can indeed find the m-th multi factorial of n.

However, I have no idea how to prove it.

I found this at the following

[In layman's terms, what is a multifactorial? - $x\underbrace{!!\cdots!}_{n\text{ times} }$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546864/in-laymans-terms-what-is-a-multifactorial-x-underbrace-cdots-n-text)

Please help me.

Comment: Can you prove it for $m=2$?

Comment: Getting induction vibes

Comment: Please tell me.When $m=2$, if $n$ is even $n!!=2^nn!$, else if $n$ is odd, $n!!=(2k)!/(2^kk!)$. This is easy. However I can't prove it.

Comment: this is the definition

Comment: If this is the definition, tell me the citiation.

Comment: [This is a citation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Generalizations). You might argue "but its recursive". Well yeah, products of more than $2$ elements are defined recursively too. Its really the same thing. There is nothing to prove here

Comment: @Jakobian Thank you. I think that my question is no worth. Sorry, everyone.